# What is "new list<int>[V]; "?

Tags: c++, std

Sorry for my noobishness but I have been trying to study graphs and have come across this code from GFG.

```
#include <list>
 
using namespace std;
 
// This class represents a directed graph using
// adjacency list representation
class Graph
{
    int V;    // No. of vertices
 
    // Pointer to an array containing adjacency
    // lists
    list<int> *adj;   
public:
    Graph(int V);  // Constructor
 
    // function to add an edge to graph
    void addEdge(int v, int w); 
 
    // prints BFS traversal from a given source s
    void BFS(int s);  
};
 
Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<int>[V];
}
 
void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
    adj[v].push_back(w); // Add w to v’s list.
}
```

I have some questions:

1. What does `new list<int>[V];` do?
2. What is meant by `list<int> * adj;`?
3. Could anyone suggest a better code that does the same thing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: this is "geek-style". They use it in many of their examples. I don't understand why they use a standard container in one place but fall back to a manually managed array in others. Often they add variable length arrays to the mix. Honestly I cannot recommend this site for beginners

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 -- The geek site has no peer-reviewed material.  Any slop programming gets posted there as "tutorials".   I saw one comment on there from a well-versed C++ programmer practically ripping to shreds one of their tutorials.  It was sad. @OP -- `list<int> *adj;` Change to: `std::vector<std::list<int>> adj;` and make the other appropriate changes.

Comment: its an array of `std::list`, `std::list` is likely to give poorer performance than `std::vector` in a lot of cases, dynamically allocating an array is likely to make it even worse

Comment: `new list<int>[V]` allocates a dynamic array of lists of integers and `list<int>*adj` is a variable which points to that dynamic array. As the comments above say, this is not a style to be emulated. Replace the dynamic array with a vector.

Comment: geeksforgeeks is not worth what you're spending on it.

Answer (score 1):

1/ It dynamically allocates a C-style array of size V, filled with `list<int>` objects

2/ It's a pointer on the array created in 1.

3/ I'd also suggest to not mix C and C++ and instead use `std::vector` to manage your array of `list<int>`

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Graph
{
    // Check https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector
    vector<list<int>> adj;   
public:
    Graph(size_t vertices);

    void addEdge(size_t vert, int w); 

    void BFS(int s);  
};

Graph::Graph(size_t vertices)
: adj(vertices)
{
}

void Graph::addEdge(size_t vert, int w)
{
    if (adj.size() <= vert) { 
        // Either print an error and stop the program
        // or call adj.resize(vert) and proceed
    }
    adj.at(vert).push_back(w);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `new<int>[V]` allocates an array of `V` empty `list<int>`'s on the heap. This array must be manually freed by calling `delete[]` on it (probably in the `Graph` destructor), or the memory will leak.
2. `list<int> *adj`, which appears in the declaration of the `Graph` class, is a pointer to a `list<int>`.  The `Graph` constructor assigns this pointer to point to the beginning of the array allocated by `new`.
3. I agree with m88's answer to (3). It would be better to use a `vector<list<int>>` to hold the lists rather than manually manage them with `new` and `delete`.